# Dataframe _ Replace / Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm trying to remove the characters in parentheses, in dataframe.

I tried  below, but it didn't work.

`df['contents'] = df['contents'].str.replace(pat='([.,!?"\':;~()[]]+\[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+[.,!?"\':;~()[]])', repl ='', regex = False)`

for example (in dataframe)
[abc]def
=> def

thanks for your insight.

Comment: are there multiple groups of square brackets?  And can you clarify, square brackets `[]` or parentheses `()`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead try this:

```
df['contents'] = df['contents'].str.replace(pat=r's/\([^)]*\)//', repl ='', regex = True)
```